# Is there already a method for dealing with pile on answers?

Tags: discussion

So, this might be covered under one of the other sites, but is there a preferred way to deal with "pile on" answers?  I speak specifically of those answers that say something like "as X said, restate of X's answer, additional comment that adds nothing to the answer."  Is this a down vote situation? Add a comment that says this should be a comment and not an answer? Just flag for delete?

What's the best way to deal with these?

Answer (score 5):

If they really just *reference* another answer and aren't complete on their own (and don't add anything substantive), you could flag them, although I would just downvote them and leave a comment explaining it.  You should only really flag *non-answers*, and these sound like real answers, just poor ones - although you haven't provided a specific example, so I'm making a few assumptions there.

Also, if you see a particular question getting a lot of pointless/noisy answers then flag the question itself for moderator attention and we'll either protect it or close/lock it if the situation seems particularly dire.

In general, don't be afraid to downvote anything that looks like crap.  People may cry bloody murder over a downvote but in practice, they are just as vital as upvotes to maintain the quality of answers and thus the overall health of this community.

Comment: I didn't really want to call out a bunch of new users which is the reason for the lack of specific examples.  I just wanted to discourage the behavior in the way that everybody thought would minimize waves.